# 3-phase inductance calculation homework

Tags: three-phase, inductance, homework, s-parameters

This is a homework question where i am stuck. Please help me out in this:

> Three similar impedances are connected in star across 2000 V, 50 Hz three phase 
>   supply. Power absorbed is 300 kW. Current taken is 100 A lagging. Find the values of circuit parameters in each phase.

I have found out the power factor to be 0.866.

I found out the impedance Z to be |Vph| / |Iph| = 11.243 ohms.

But now how do we find the inductance of the circuit?

Comment: Same question can be seen [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/499904/three-phase-system-questions).

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.  What is the apparent power of the load (kva)?

Comment: But the other question's answers dont talk about inductance.

Comment: Apparent power i found it out to be 346410.1615 va.

Comment: Now you can find the angle of your load Z from power triangle. Angle = arccos(kw/kva).  You know it will be lagging angle as was given.  Tom lays it out well.

Comment: *But now how do we find the inductance of the circuit?* - you can't because you don't know if the inductance is parallel to the resistor or in series with the resistor. The load is not defined as a series-elements or parallel-elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should determine the impedance of your load using complex numbers. Once you know the impedance, you can find out the reactive component \$X\$ directly:

$$Z = R + jX$$

The sign of the reactive part of your impedance indicates whether you have an more capacitive (negative reactance) or a more inductive (positive reactance) load. You can then convert from reactance to capacitance or inductance if you know frequency:

$$X_C = (-j)\frac{1}{\omega C}$$
$$X_L = (j)\omega L$$

Comment: Thanks but how do i find out the angle of phase current?  I found out the angle of phase voltage is -30 degrees.

Comment: You already have it - the power factor is cosine of the the phase angle between voltage and current.

Comment: Ok thanks.I figured out resistance  and then inductance.Thanks